# Do I need to retain parameters passed to custom initWith method?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

for example:

in interface:

```
@property(retain) NSObject* anObject;
```

in interface,
in implemetation:

```
-(id)initWithAnotherObject:(NSObject*)another{
    if(self = [super init]){
         anObject = another;    //should this be anObject = [another retain]?
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Where you have `NSObject` in your code examples, you really need `NSObject*`. Objective-C objects are always passed by reference, but unlike Java, you must explicitly tell the compiler by using pointers to `NSObject`.

Comment: oh, this is a typo, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as you cannot guarantee that 'another' lifetime will be the same as lifetime of the object you create you need to ensure that by retaining it in init method (and do not forget to release it in dealloc method). So the following is correct:

```
...
if(self = [super init]){
     anObject = [another retain];
}
...
```

One more thing - by defining retaining property for anObject you say that you take an ownership of that object and thus you must release it in dealloc method. If you don't retain 'another' parameter in init method it will be eventually released (either in dealloc or in setter method) without being retained - so your application may crash with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good practice to do

```
self.anObject = another;
```

but it's the same

Comment: It is not the same, by using self you are invoking the setter which could be synthetized as retain.